# android 9 - listview lines shifting left

Tags: android

ListView lines are shifting only at Android 9

Yesterday i have update my phone with new android 9 and the problem has occurred.

please see the picture at the link below:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bPe-UqaGzhTkZ34IyjfwMx9Dq0zIJUBQ

the right side is android 9 and the left side is android 8.

it is the same code with the same emulator proprieties and the only difference is the android version.

it is happened also on the physical devices with android 9 only.

here is the XML of the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/importContactPopup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#E4E4E4"
    tools:context="com.gmail.zionrevi.zigi.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="בחירת יחידות"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/activeColor"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_tab_focus"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_tab"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context="com.gmail.zionrevi.zigi.MainActivity">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxAll"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:buttonTint="@color/activeColor"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxAllTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:text="בחר הכל"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@color/activeColor"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/popupUnitsList"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_tab"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_tab"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/popupDone"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_active_style"
            android:text="בצע"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:textColor="@color/activeColor"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/popupCancel"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_active_style"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="בטל"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:textColor="@color/activeColor"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is the XML of the line items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/frame_tab"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:context="com.gmail.zionrevi.zigi.MainActivity">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxUnit"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/activeColor"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chooseUnit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@color/activeColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is anyone have any idea how to solved it?

Answer (score 0):

i have bypass the problem by changing the LinearLayout to RelativeLayout as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/chooseUnitLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/frame_tab"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.gmail.zionrevi.zigi.PreQuestionnaireActivity">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxUnit"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/activeColor"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chooseUnit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/checkBoxUnit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@color/activeColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

which is only a workaround and not a real solution. so i will be glade to understand what is wrong in my previous layout or the problem is at Android 9.